# Why does a syscall clobber rcx and r11?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64, system-calls

In the book [*Low-Level Programming: C, Assembly, and Program Execution on Intel® 64 Architecture*](https://www.apress.com/us/book/9781484224021) it says,

> **On system call arguments** The arguments for system calls are stored in a different set of registers than those for functions. The fourth argument is stored in `r10` , while a function accepts the fourth argument in `rcx`!
>
> The reason is that `syscall` instruction implicitly uses `rcx`. System calls cannot accept more than six
>   arguments.

You can see this also mentioned in this [Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2538212/124486),

> A system-call is done via the syscall instruction. This clobbers %rcx and %r11, as well as %rax, but other registers are preserved.

I understand clobbering `rax` to store the return code, but why is `rcx`, and `r11` clobbered in `syscall`? Is there a list of the specific syscalls that clobber `rcx`/`r11`? Is there a convention for the clobbering? Are they assumed safe in any syscalls?

Comment: `syscall` does that. There is no stack switch, it's too late for the kernel.

Answer (score 7):

The [syscall](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/SYSCALL.html) instruction uses `rcx` to store the address of the next instruction to return to, and `r11` to save the value of the `rflags` register. These values will then be restored by the `sysret` instruction.

This is done by the CPU when executing the CPU instruction, so any OS-specific calling conventions need to avoid using these registers to pass arguments to syscalls.

Comment: What's the purpose of saving the value of rflags in `r11`, rather than just leaving it there?

Comment: @EvanCarroll It will be restored to rflags when the call returns. I think it's done in order to restore some of the more important flags which may be changed by the kernel code.

Comment: @EvanCarroll `sysret` also masks (ANDs) `rflags` before handing control to the OS. That'd be impossible without first saving `rflags`. You can take a look at the [`syscall`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/SYSCALL.html) manual entry for more information.