# ASM: Seg faults on loop, unsure why

Tags: macos, assembly, segmentation-fault, x86-64, nasm

I've written the following program in NASM x86, but all I seem to get when I try to run it are segfaults (when trying to print) and infinite loops when I stop the printing. The code manages to call `printNumber` successfully ONCE, and then segfaults; because of this I am led to believe it is something happening in the second iteration of the loop. What am I missing here? I've added comments to my source to explain what's happening, but I cannot understand why this is throwing segfaults for what should be a simple program (don't have access to valgrind or gdb at the moment).

This is the output:

> `0Segmentation fault: 11`

.. And here is the small program I wrote. What am I not seeing here?

```
SECTION .data
    arraylen dd 10
    num db 0
    farewell: db "Blah"
SECTION .bss
    array resq 8

SECTION .text
    global start

start:
    call fillArr
    mov rax, 0x02000001
    mov rdi, 0
    syscall

printNum:
    mov rsi, num
    mov rdx, 2
    call print
    ret

fillArr:
    lea rsi, [rel array] ; needed for 64 bit on mac
    xor rcx, rcx ; make this 0
    arrayloop:
        mov [rsi+rcx*8], rcx ; array element rcx updated with value
        mov rbx, [rsi + rcx*8] ; grab value at index we just filled

        add rbx, 48 ; now offset number by 48 to make it ascii'able
        mov [rsi+rcx*8], rbx ; overwritten the value we saw as it's ascii
        mov [rel num], rbx ; update storage var
        call printNum ; print
        inc rcx ; we don't need this anymore
        cmp rcx, 4
        jne arrayloop

    mov rsi, farewell
    mov rdx, 4
    call print
    ret

print:
    mov rax, 0x02000004
    mov rdi, 1
    syscall
    ret
```

Comment: What OS is involved?  What operation is `rax=0x2000004` supposed to do?

Comment: macOS, 64bit. I use the following commands to compile it:

nasm -f macho64 arr.asm
ld -macosx_version_min 10.7.0 -lSystem -o arrayTest arr.o

That operation is equivalent to the sys call 4 on Linux (so print)

Comment: I'd run it in a debugger (like `lldb`) step by step but just looking at the code one concern I have is that `syscall` (the instruction itself) clobbers RCX and R11. You don't use R11 but it does seem your code relies on RCX not being clobbered in function `fillArr`. You could try preserving RCX in function `print` by saving (ie: PUSH RCX) and restoring it before returning (ie: POP RCX)

Comment: @wallyk: It was tagged MacOS from the start.  Call numbers like that are what MacOS uses for "normal" POSIX system calls like `read` and `write`.  Of course, good source code would comment each `syscall` with exactly what system call it was actually making.

Comment: @PeterCordes:  I misread `macos` and thought it was `macros`!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is here when called from `printNum`:

```
print:
    mov rax, 0x02000004
    mov rdi, 1
    syscall
    ret
```

As @MichaelPrefetch and @PeterCordes mentioned in the comments `syscall` clobbers rcx and r11. See [also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50571275/why-does-a-syscall-clobber-rcx-and-r11) (it's a linux tagged answer but in this regard the kernel behavior is identical to MacOS in x86-64). If you're curious how it works [under the hood](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47997378/5329717) when not single stepping with a debugger rcx after the `syscall` will contain its return address which will be your program next instruction (`ret` in this case).

Since your `arrayloop` logic relies on rcx afterwards this will fail with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` in this line:

```
arrayloop:
    mov [rsi+rcx*8], rcx ; array element rcx updated with value
```

A possible fix might look like this:

```
print:
    mov rax, 0x02000004
    mov rdi, 1
    push rcx
    syscall
    pop rcx
    ret
```

which preserves rcx value on the stack and immediately restores its value right after the `syscall`.

As an *alternative* @PeterCordes suggests to refactor the loop not to rely on rcx at all. There are plenty of remaining registers to pick from(except aforementioned r11 and rax,rdx used for `syscall` return value).

Comment: The normal way would be to pick a call-preserved register for a loop that contains function calls, rather than inventing a calling convention where functions save RCX.  Also, `syscall` always destroys RCX, regardless of what value ends up there when it eventually returns.  No real need to go into detail about what the kernel does after `syscall` itself destroys the old value before the kernel gets control; that's enough to explain why it's not preserved.

Comment: This was the issue! Thank you all for the help, can't believe I forgot about the syscall's side effects.

Comment: @Kamil: Neither of us mentioned that syscall also clobbers R11 (although Michael Petch did in comments) >.<.  The OP stepped on that next: [CMP Instruction and JE not firing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64409124)  Next time, remember to mention both destroyed registers.  Or just link [Why does a syscall clobber rcx and r11?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50571275)

Comment: @PeterCordes I've edited the answer in spirit of your remarks. Thank you.